# emacs autocomplete for C++

Tags: emacs

I am trying to set emacs for c++ programming.
Mostly followed the instructions here..http://truongtx.me/2013/03/10/emacs-setting-up-perfect-environment-for-cc-programming/
Everything works great except the autocomplete for which I followed instructions here
http://truongtx.me/2013/03/06/emacs-ccpp-autocomplete-with-clang/

As per instructions, [C-] should be binded but when I press [ctrl + '-'] I dont see any suggestions..
Here is my .emacs file

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(package-refresh-contents)


(require 'cc-mode)
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4 c-default-style "linux")
(setq-default tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode t)
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)

(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/mohit/Documents/scratch/autopair")
(require 'autopair)
(autopair-global-mode 1)
(setq autopair-autowrap t)

(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/mohit/Documents/scratch/ecb")
(require 'ecb)
(setq ecb-layout-name "left8")
(setq ecb-show-sources-in-directories-buffer 'always)
(setq ecb-compile-window-height 12)

;;; activate and deactivate ecb
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-;") 'ecb-activate)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-'") 'ecb-deactivate)
;;; show/hide ecb window
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'ecb-show-ecb-windows)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'ecb-hide-ecb-windows)
;;; quick navigation between ecb windows
(global-set-key (kbd "C-)") 'ecb-goto-window-edit1)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-!") 'ecb-goto-window-directories)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-@") 'ecb-goto-window-sources)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-#") 'ecb-goto-window-methods)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-$") 'ecb-goto-window-compilation)

;;; replacement for built-in ecb-deactive, ecb-hide-ecb-windows and
;;; ecb-show-ecb-windows functions
;;; since they hide/deactive ecb but not restore the old windows for me
(defun tmtxt/ecb-deactivate ()
  "deactive ecb and then split emacs into 2 windows that contain 2 most recent buffers"
  (interactive)
  (ecb-deactivate)
  (split-window-right)
  (switch-to-next-buffer)
  (other-window 1))
(defun tmtxt/ecb-hide-ecb-windows ()
  "hide ecb and then split emacs into 2 windows that contain 2 most recent buffers"
  (interactive)
  (ecb-hide-ecb-windows)
  (split-window-right)
  (switch-to-next-buffer)
  (other-window 1))
(defun tmtxt/ecb-show-ecb-windows ()
  "show ecb windows and then delete all other windows except the current one"
  (interactive)
  (ecb-show-ecb-windows)
  (delete-other-windows))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-'") 'tmtxt/ecb-deactivate)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'tmtxt/ecb-show-ecb-windows)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-'") 'tmtxt/ecb-hide-ecb-windows)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

(setq package-user-dir "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
(package-initialize)

;;; (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-1.4/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
;;; set the trigger key so that it can work together with yasnippet on tab key,
;;; if the word exists in yasnippet, pressing tab will cause yasnippet to
;;; activate, otherwise, auto-complete will
(ac-set-trigger-key "TAB")
(ac-set-trigger-key "<tab>")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-clang/")
(require 'auto-complete-clang)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-`") 'ac-complete-clang)
```

Comment: It looks like you've bound `C-\``, not `C--`, to `ac-complete-clang`. Does that key combination properly trigger completion?

Comment: @Chris: Yeah you are correct.. Also, this seems to be doing code completion for the my libraries but is there a way to do code completion for the standard C++ libraries (say string, iostream and for third party libraries (say boost) ) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `ac-complete-clang` bound to `` C-` ``, not to `C--`; it should work if you trigger it with the correct bindng.

As explained in [the troubleshooting section of `auto-complete-clang`'s README](https://github.com/brianjcj/auto-complete-clang#troubleshooting), you may have to manually point `auto-complete-clang` at your system libraries:

> - clang fails to find the standard inlcude files?
>
>   It is because clang’s include file search path is not correct. Here is the solution:
> - find out the include file search pathes of your g++:
>
>   ```
>   echo "" | g++ -v -x c++ -E -
>   ```
>
>   you wil get something like this:
>
>   ```
>   #include "..." search starts here：
>   #include <...> search starts here：
>    /usr/include/c++/4.6
>    /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
>    /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
>    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
>    /usr/local/include
>    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
>    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
>    /usr/include
>   End of search list.
>   ```
> - setting the ac-clang-flags to include these default include pathes. e.g.,
>
>   ```
>   (setq ac-clang-flags
>         (mapcar (lambda (item)(concat "-I" item))
>                 (split-string
>                  "
>    /usr/include/c++/4.6
>    /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
>    /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
>    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
>    /usr/local/include
>    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
>    /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
>    /usr/include
>   "
>                  )))
>   ```
>
> You can put it into your .emacs file.
>
> Then code completion works just fine!